# varying pwm on an arduino through visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, serial-communication, pwm

So I am  making a user interface on vb 2010 that allows the user to type in a textbox the PWM they want a value between 0-255. I want to be able to take the value and change it as much as i want but there seems to be a problem i am only able to send one value without needing to debug the program again. The LED I am using as the test doesn't seem to be responding with the equivalent level brightness for the PWM that i use in the textbox. I hope to be able to control this with 8 separate relays as the end goal using some sort of switch statement. Any help would be very nice my current code:
VB

```
 Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Shared _continue As Boolean
    Shared _serialPort As SerialPort
    Dim SerialPort1 As SerialPort
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SerialPort1 = New SerialPort
        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM4"
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
        SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
        SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
        SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
        SerialPort1.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim input As String
        Dim returnvalue As String

        input = TextBox1.Text
        returnvalue = input


        SerialPort1.Write(input)
        SerialPort1.Close()


        MessageBox.Show(returnvalue)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim a As Integer
        a = SerialPort1.ReadChar()
        MessageBox.Show(a)
    End Sub
End Class



Arduino
   void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   // initialize the LED pins:
      int thisPin = 2;
        pinMode(thisPin, OUTPUT);
      }

void loop() { 
    int inByte= 0;
    int V1;
  if (Serial.available()) {
     inByte = Serial.read();
     V1 = inByte;
      analogWrite(2, V1);
  }
}

Any help would be awesome ive been stumped on this for awhile
```

Comment: Q: Should you really be doing that `SerialPort1.Close()` in Button1_Click()???  Also: look [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=185085.0) and [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=185740.0).

Answer (score 0):

I have little experince with VB 2000. But I can answer the Arduino side. Looks like you are reading bytes in Arduino (1 at time)

```
 inByte = Serial.read();
```

But looks like you are sending text in the VB2000 App

```
 SerialPort1.Write(input)
```

Can you confirme that? If so, you need to transform the text input to Integer and then send 1 byte only.

Comment: Yes im sending text from vb 2010 to the arduino in the form of a number between 0-255 that will represent the pwm cycle so that i can chang e the brightness of an LED

Comment: After 
        SerialPort1.Write(input)
You dont need to use somethink like "flush" to really send the data?